# Is it ever OK to throw a java.lang.Error?

Tags: java, web-applications, error-handling

I have a plugin module that goes into a web application.
If the module does not load correctly, it does not make sense for the web application to go on, and the web application should probably not load at all, we would prefer this module to initialize correctly always.
If I were to throw a runtime exception, it would get into the logs, and just get ignored since the application will continue anyway, and the end users would never know...
I know that errors are meant to be thrown only under exceptional conditions, and they generally have to do with situations that the system cannot recover from, but what would you do in such a situation?

Comment: Shouldn't be Error, but some suitable subclass, either existing or one you define.  But throwing a subclass of Error is appropriate in your situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *only* `Error` which I've regularly used in business code is [`ExceptionInInitializerError`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html). You have no other choice in `static` initializer blocks.

But even if you throw that inside a webapplication, the webapplication would still continue listening on HTTP requests. Your best bet is to do the module loading or initialization inside a `Filter` listening on an `url-pattern` of `/*` and let the `Filter` block the HTTP requests accordingly. E.g.

```
private boolean allModulesAreLoaded;

@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) {
    try {
        // Load modules.
        allModulesAreLoaded = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle.
    }
}

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    if (allModulesAreLoaded) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    } else {
        throw new ServletException("Not all modules are loaded.");
    }
}
```

This would yield a HTTP 500 error with the given message.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how exactly but OSGi got a dependency management of bundles (=similar to plugins). One bundle don't load until another bundle is ready. Maybe you can use this same mechanism (or simply use OSGi itself ;)) to wait for one plugin/application until another plugin is ready. Or you shutdown the application during startup if it cannot find/load your plugin correctly.

Comment: Seems like the hammer of all nails, however being fond of OSGi, I tend to approvde. Besides, any kind of dependency management mechanism should work (IoC, you name it).

Answer (score -1):

Log the error, and then use System.Exit to just exit the application

Comment: That provides no indication (beyond the return code) as to why the app failed.

Comment: @HotLicks I added a suggestion to first log the error and then exit.